# Deletion in Priority Queue

Tags: java, android, data-structures

I have a code (Andorid) which iterates through a priority queue and deletes all entries with a particular id.

However, it deletes only the first instance and skips the rest. For example,

(abc 1) 
(def 2)
(ghi 3)
(jkl 1)
(mno 3)

If given id is 1. It only deletes abc and the queue gets reorganized and leaves jkl in it. I also tired iterator but of no use.

```
for(SomeMessage message : priorityQueue){

          if(message.id == dead_sender.id){
                      priorityQueue.remove(message)
       }

}
```

Comment: Does this code really work? It shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot iterate the collection in a for-each loop and delete elements from it while doing so.

You should create a separate set for "items to remove" while iterating. When you have finished, iterate over this new set, deleting each item from the original collection.

Something like:

```
List<SomeMessage> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();
for(SomeMessage message : priorityQueue){

          if(message.id == dead_sender.id){
                      toRemove.add(message);
       }
}
for (SomeMessage message : toRemove) { 
      priorityQueue.remove(message)
}
```

---

Note, however, that removing an arbitrary element (not the head) of a priority queue is an expensive task (`O(n)`), and if that becomes an issue you might need change your design to:

1. Use a `TreeSet` or a fully ordered data structure
2. Instead of marking which items to remove, mark which items to keep - and instead of removing them - build a new PriorityQueue with these items.

Comment: Or, for that matter, don't mark at all, but instead build the new structure while iterating over the old. There are also structures called priority search queues that support both efficient priority queue operations and efficient searching.

Comment: @dfeuer That really depends on how many items needed to be deleted, anyway - laat part of the answer should cover that